# what is the Maximum users request for a open cart site?

Tags: php, opencart

can any one tell me that how many users can access open cart site at a single time?

I mean that how many requests can be handled by the open cart i a same time?

or else is it depends on the hosting server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That as with all web applications depends on the hosting/server not the software

Comment: Well, there are few software products, that limit those numbers due to license characteristics. But I don't think that this holds true for opencart.

Comment: correct, OC doesn't apply any limits to the software

Comment: okay. thanks a lot.. can any one provide me sample link that exaplain's more about this?